# Limit v/s limitation

Tags: word-usage

I suffer from over reading.  Have I again?  I was looking for a new contract when I 
arrived at Octapace Consulting. Here is a quote that anchors that page.  It reads:

“When you compete with a person, you only have to be as good or better than the person to win. If you compete with yourself, there is no limitation to how good you can be.”

Shouldn't it read (note limit edit only):

“When you compete with a person, you only have to be as good as that person to win. If you compete with yourself, there is no limit to how good you can be."

The question.  Limitation v/s limit.  Shouldn't there be no "limit" to what can be achieved?  They use "limitation" which isn't quite the same thing.

===================

Two asides for comments.  Please ignore them.  Does "a person" advance to "the person", or should it be "that person"?   Or does it even matter.

If indeed you can win being as "good as" then it's not necessary for "or better".  In fact, I'd say, it kind of subverts the message.  This may be more of style question.  What do you think?

Please limit minus counts to 3 - I only have 150 points left.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say *limit* is more idiomatic than *limitation* for your exact context. But I don't think you can really say [there is no limitation to (something that's not limited)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22there+is+no+limitation+to%22) is "invalid", given that's a claimed  19,700 results from Google Books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Limit' has a zero derivation.  It can be used as either a noun or a verb.
The noun can also be derived in the normal way, by adding '[t]ion', but 'limitation' is an ugly word because it looks like a noun 'limit' that went to verb 'limitate' that went back to noun 'limitation'.

Comment: Nice explanation for why *limit* is better than *limitation*. Next assignment, resurrect [*indention*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/indention), which somehow was usurped by *indentation*.